# How to adjust size of Seaborn distribution graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, google-colaboratory

I would like to adjust the size of this distribution plot in `Seaborn`. I tried a few ways from online tutorials and the docs but nothing seemed to actually work. I find this really confusing as it appears different plots such as `plt`, `sns` have different functions which don't seem to work interchangeably...

My code:

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.distplot(df['data'])
g.fig.set_figwidth(20)
g.fig.set_figheight(10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

g is an `matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot` (try `type(g)` to see that). If you do a `dir(g)` you would see that it has no `fig` method/attribute. But it has a `figure` attribute. So change your code to reflect that and you would have what you need.

```
import seaborn as sns
g = sns.distplot(df['data'])
g.figure.set_figwidth(20)
g.figure.set_figheight(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Sinan Kurmus's answer, just an alternative solution:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(30,10))   # Use this line            
# plt.gcf().subplots_adjust(left = 0.3)
g = sns.distplot(df['data'])
```